# Error al intentar insertar registro en la BD mediante php

Tags: php

Saludos estoy intentando insertar un registro en mi Base de Datos y me da un error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '20210224132237', '4', 2, 16, 1, 1...' at line 15

A continuación mi código

```
    <?php 
session_start();
include "./conexion.php";
$arreglousuario = $_SESSION['datos_logueo'];
$id = $arreglousuario['id_usuario'];
$fecha = new DateTime();

if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['descripcion']) 
&& isset($_POST['precio']) && isset($_POST['ubicacion']) 
&& isset($_POST['telefono1']) && isset($_POST['estado']) && isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['subcategoria'])){
   
  if(!empty($_POST['caracteristicas']) || !empty($_POST['marca']) || !empty($_POST['modelo']) || !empty($_POST['edicion']) ||  !empty($_POST['inventario']) || !empty($_POST['telefono2'])){    
  $sql = $conexion ->query ("insert into publicacion
  (nombre,descripcion,caracteristicas,marca,modelo,edicion,precio,inventario,
  ubicacion,telefono1,telefono2,fecha_publicacion,id_estatus,id_usuario,id_estado,id_categoria,id_subcategoria) values
      ( 
      '".$_POST['nombre']."',
      '".$_POST['descripcion']."',
      '".$_POST['caracteristicas']."',
      '".$_POST['marca']."',
      '".$_POST['modelo']."',
      '".$_POST['edicion']."',
      ".$_POST['precio'].",
      ".$_POST['inventario'].",
      '".$_POST['ubicacion']."',
      ".$_POST['telefono1'].",
      ".$_POST['telefono2'].",
      '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
      '4',
      $id,
      ".$_POST['estado'].",
      ".$_POST['categoria'].",
      ".$_POST['subcategoria']."
      )
")or die ($conexion->error);
                     header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?success");
                    }else{


                    $sql2 = $conexion ->query ("insert into publicacion
                    (nombre,descripcion,precio,ubicacion,telefono1,fecha_publicacion,id_estatus,id_usuario,
                    id_estado,id_categoria,id_subcategoria) values
                        ( 
                        '".$_POST['nombre']."',
                        '".$_POST['descripcion']."',
                        ".$_POST['precio'].",
                        '".$_POST['ubicacion']."',
                        ".$_POST['telefono1'].",
                        '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
                        '4',
                        $id,
                        ".$_POST['estado'].",
                        ".$_POST['categoria'].",
                        ".$_POST['subcategoria']."
                        
                      )
                  ")or die ($conexion->error);
                                       header("Location: ../admin/publicacion.php?success");
                    
      }    
    }  


?>
```

****En el error me muestra '20210224132237', '4', 2, 16, 1, 1...' at line 15 el primer conjunto de números es la fecha que pertenecen al campo fecha, el '4' es el id_estatus que intento insertar, el '2' es el id del usuario que está en la sesión, el '16' es la ciudad ó estado del país, el '1' es la categoría y el último '1' la subcategoría, la verdad no entiendo por qué se ha liado en esto si lo he hecho en otros insert practicamente igual y no genera errores. Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudar.****

Comment: Imprime tus consultas completas y muéstralas en la pregunta para revisar dónde está el error de sintaxis. Deberías ir considerando dar un poco de claridad y de seguridad a tu código, evitado el uso constante de `$_POST` sin más.

Comment: Hola gracias por su respuesta, allí están las consultas están completas, ¿qué otro método podría usar para dar más seguridad al código?

Comment: Yo me refiero a las consultas que se estarían produciendo y que son las que tienen error de sintaxis por algún motivo. Pon `echo $sql;` y `echo $sql2;` y luego copia y pega el código en la pregunta. Así podremos ver dónde está el error de sintaxis. En cuanto a la seguridad, deberías usar consultas preparadas, pero ese es otro tema. Pero no lo dejes para mucho tiempo, porque tu código tal como está es vulnerable a graves ataques si el mismo está disponible en algún sitio web o va a ser destinado a otros usuarios, como ha de suponerse.

Comment: No imprime nada en las varaibles de las consultas, sigue mostrando el error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '20210224132237', '4', 2, 16, 1, 1...' at line 15

Comment: ¿Los campos de teléfono son numéricos o _varchar_? ¿Deberían estar entre comillas simples?

Comment: En efecto era ese pequeño pero gran error. En la BD tenía como tipo de dato varchar y no me acordaba y estaba manejando en la consulta el tipo de dato como si fuera numerico. Muchas gracias, también ya estoy viendo un curso de consultas preparadas voy a hacerle reingeniería a todo el código de consultas, muchas gracias nuevamente.